# Conditional distribution in R

Tags: r, self-study, distributions, conditional-probability, random-generation

I have the following exercise:

> "We consider the following model. X is a factor variable with three
>   levels a, b and c and corresponding probabilities 0:1, 0:3 and 0:6.
>   Given X, Y follows an exponential distribution with mean 1 if X = a,
>   with mean 2 if X = b and mean 10 if X = c. Simulate a sample of size
>   100 from this model. Using the function qqmath, assess whether the
>   distribution of Y given X is normal ? uniform ? exponential ?".

I computed X as follow:

```
x <- sample(c("a","b","c"),100,prob=c(0.1,0.3,0.6),rep=T)
```

How can I compute Y|X? Should I compute the joint as 
0,1*fY|X=a + 0,3*fY|X=b etc, and then plot the joint?

Is there a function in R that helps me compute a conditional pdf given that X is discrete and Y continuous?

Comment: There is obviously no _generic_ R function that "computes" $Y|X$. In the problem, the conditional distributions are well defined for each possible value of $X$ and easy to generate. However the question as reproduced is weird since the question provides the distribution of Y given X. As exponential. Why would one want to re-check this?

Comment: Checking whether Y|X is normal, uniform or exponential is not the important part of the question. My problem is simulating the model. Could you help me with that? Is my X computed right? Should I do a function or compute the joint density function and then simulate that?

Comment: Hint: consult the help for `rexp` to figure out what the expression `rexp(length(x), 1/c(a=1, b=2, c=10)[x])` might be doing.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a `self-study` question (please add the tag), here is an hint to generate $Y$ given the already simulated vector of $X$'s:

> the realized value of $X$ determines the scale of the Exponential
>   distribution of $Y$ given $X$ and an Exponential with scale $\alpha$
>   is simply $\alpha$ times an Exponential with scale 1.

And then exploit W Huber's hint in the comments.

Comment: Yes, thank you. However, is X correctly simulated? I'm new to R. I cannot use a logical if x="a", and I cannot for instance compute 2*rexp(100,1). Is there another way to define X so I can use X="a" conditions?

Comment: Yes the simulation of $X$ is correct (as you can check with an histogram). And you can definitely use a logical `x=="a"` in your R code. If your exercise requires R programming and you are new to R, you should spend some time learning R.